# What is behind the design decision to have a static method return a private class? Such as Collections.synchronizedList()

Tags: java, collections

I wanted to extend the SynchronizedList class but found it to be private.

Why was it designed this way?

Comment: Because the person who designed it doesn't want you to extend it. The precise reason for doing it is known only to the designer(s), but consider the advice in *Effective Java 2nd Ed* Item 17: "Design and document for inheritance or else prohibit it". It simplifies the implementation of a class if you don't have to worry about somebody extending it.

Comment: Plus one. IMHO a short question is not necessarily a poor one.

Comment: What behaviour do you want to add to the class? It might be possible to add it to the list wrapped by the `SynchronizedList` instead.

Comment: The real question is "Why do you want to extend it?" Methinks this may be an instance of the [xy-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Thank you for your comments. My intended question was regarding the design decision on having a static method to  returning a private class, I think Andy Turner has answered it in that it simplifies the implementation, but I don't fully understand why it does currently.

Comment: I have changed the question title to be clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the person who designed it doesn't want you to extend it.

The precise reason for doing it is known only to the designer(s), but consider the advice in Effective Java 2nd Ed Item 17:

> Design and document for inheritance or else prohibit it.

It simplifies the implementation of a class if you don't have to worry about somebody extending it. The Effective Java item gives a lot of detail of the sorts of problems that you have to design for, and the steps necessary to mitigate them.

One could argue that it was laziness on the part of the class designers not to put the effort into "designing and documenting for inheritance". In the specific case of the `Collections.Synchronized*` classes, I don't believe this: class design is always a compromise; I think that the designers weighed the benefits of putting in that extra effort against the very limited number of use cases of extending a synchronized collection. (I have never thought to try to extend the class; admittedly that is a sample size of 1, though).

After all, this is a wrapper class: you can alternatively add the additional functionality to the class wrapped by the `Synchronized*` class, or wrap the `Synchronized*` class in a decorator. Or, you can simply reimplement the `Synchronized*` class yourself - it's a bunch of boilerplate, but it isn't hard.

Whichever way you choose, you can work around it.

Comment: Thanks for your help Andy Turner. You have inspired me to read Effective Java